# How do I connect to two networks (wired and Wi-Fi) at the same time?

Tags: networking

at office i need to connect to local resources through wired network and internet thought wifi. I had tried enabling settings/network/ethernet/advanced settings/IPv4/Routes/Use this connection only for resources on its network. and i got the lan conection but the internet connection sometimes work and sometimes not, then i just need to unplug the cable, reload the browser and when i get back internet connection, replug the cable.
Also i had tried looking for the `ip route` getting only the wireless conection as default:

```
default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlp3s0  proto static  metric 600 
192.168.0.0/24 dev wlp3s0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.105  metric 600 
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp2s0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.208  metric 100
```

In ubuntu-gnome 16.10 i got this working but in elementary loki i got this problem.

Some ideas about it?

Thanks in advance!

PD: Sorry for my bad english

Comment: Due to the askubuntu website:
[How to connect to LAN and WiFi at the same time](http://askubuntu.com/questions/639100/how-to-get-connection-to-both-wifi-as-well-as-lan-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts) :)

Comment: Sure, i had try this and still the wired conection overlap the wifi, not allowing internet access

Answer (score 1):

i had solved this by adding some lines to /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto enp2s0
iface enp2s0 inet dhcp
metric 601
```

where enp2s0 is my wired interface and 601 is the new metric having wifi 600 metric.